# Error calling updateStateByKey in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have this generic method in Scala

```
def updateStateByKey[S](updateFunc: JFunction2[JList[V], Optional[S],
Optional[S]])   : JavaPairDStream[K, S] = { ... }
```

When I call it in Java, both of these does not compile:

## 1

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateDstream =
pairs.<Integer>updateStateByKey(...);
```

## 2

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateDstream =
pairs.updateStateByKey(...);
```

How do I invoke the method correctly?

Error messages:

```
The method updateStateByKey(Function2<List<Integer>,Optional<S>,Optional<S>>,
int) in the type JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> is not applicable for
the arguments
(Function2<List<Integer>,Optional<Integer>,Optional<Integer>>,
HashPartitioner, JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>)
```

Edited:
The whole function call (Java 8):

```
final Function2<List<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>> updateFunction =
    (values, state) -> {
      Integer newSum = state.or(0);
      for (Integer value : values) {
        newSum += value;
      }
      return Optional.of(newSum);
    };



JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateDstream = pairs.updateStateByKey(
    updateFunction
    ,
    new HashPartitioner(context.defaultParallelism()), initialRDD);
```

Edited:
It turned out that generics is not the issue, but the parameters do not match the method signature.

Comment: And the whole code (for the function calls in Java) ! Yet, the first way is wrong without doubt

Comment: Updated the error message

Comment: The genericity does not seem to be the problem. Show us the arguments of the function call

Comment: Sure, I added the whole call.

Comment: Your Scala method only takes one parameter, you are passing two. However, the error message does not seem to correspond to the posted code (different signature both of the method declaration and call). What is the relation between JList and List ?

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the other two parameters are wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in an `initialRDD`, while the method [`updateStateByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream) does not have that as a parameter.

The closest signature is:

```
updateStateByKey[S](updateFunc: Function2[List[V], Optional[S], Optional[S]], 
  partitioner: Partitioner): JavaPairDStream[K, S]
```